# What is the value of the limit $\lim_{a\searrow 0}\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n^{a}}$?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

Clearly the series
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n^{a}}
$$
converges (conditionally), as an alternating series of as absolutely decreasing sequence, for all $a>0$.

The question is: *What is the value of* 
$$
\lim_{a\searrow 0}\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n^{a}}.
$$
**First attempt**
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n^{a}}=\frac{a}{2}\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^{a+1}}+{\mathcal O}(a).
$$

Comment: The value is $\frac{1}{2}$ by plugging in low values to $a$. There is the riemann zeta function involved, if you wanna solve it analytically.

Answer (score 5):

The series is, for $\operatorname{Re} a > 0$, the [Dirichlet $\eta$ function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_eta_function),

$$\eta(a) = \left(1-2^{1-a}\right)\zeta(a).$$

Since $\eta$ is an entire function, by continuity, the limit is

$$\eta(0) = -\zeta(0) = \frac{1}{2}.$$

Comment: $\zeta(0)=\infty$ - In fact $\zeta(a)=\infty$, for $a<1$.

Comment: No, $\zeta$ is an entire meromorphic function, with only one pole, at $1$. $\zeta(0) = -\frac{1}{2}$. The series representation is only valid for $\operatorname{Re} s > 1$, but by alternating, we get the [Dirichlet $\eta$ function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_eta_function) whose series representation is valid for $\operatorname{Re} s > 0$. But, since $\eta$ is an entire holomorphic function, $\lim_{a\searrow 0} \eta(a) = \eta(0)$.

Comment: Indeed, it diverges ${\large\it unless}$ we interpret the sum as a Dirichlet or Riemman business which leads to an analytical continuation.

Answer (score 3):

The answer of D. Fischer is shorter and elegant. Let me nevertheless provide my own elementary answer:

First note that
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(\frac{1}{(2n-1)^a}-\frac{1}{(2n)^a}\right)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(\frac{(2n)^a-(2n-1)^a}{(2n-1)^a(2n)^a}\right)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(1+\frac{1}{2n-1})^a-1}{(2n)^a} \\
=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\frac{a}{2n-1}+\frac{a(a-1)}{2(2n-1)^2}+\cdots}{(2n)^a}=\cdots=\frac{a}{2}\sum_{n=1}^\infty
\frac{1}{n^{a+1}}+{\mathcal O}(a).
$$
Next obrserve that, there exists $\xi,\zeta\in (0,1)$, such that
$$
\frac{1}{n^{a+1}}-\int_{n}^{n+1}\frac{dx}{x^{a+1}}=\frac{1}{n^{a+1}}-\frac{1}{(n+\xi)^{a+1}}=
\frac{\xi(a+1)}{(n+\zeta)^{a+2}},
$$
and hence
$$
0<\frac{1}{n^{a+1}}-\int_{n}^{n+1}\frac{dx}{x^{a+1}}< 
\frac{a+1}{n^{2}},
$$
which implies that
$$
\frac{a}{2}\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n^{a+1}}=\frac{a}{2}\int_1^\infty\frac{dx}{x^{a+1}}+{\mathcal O}(a).
$$
But
$$
\frac{a}{2}\int_1^\infty\frac{dx}{x^{a+1}}=\lim_{M\to\infty}\frac{a}{2}\left(\frac{1}{a}-\frac{1}{aM^a}\right)=\frac{1}{2},
$$
which implies that
$$
\lim_{a\searrow 0}\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n^{a}}=\frac{1}{2}.
$$

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\Li}[1]{\,{\rm Li}_{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
With $\ds{n\in{\mathbb N}\,,\ N\ \geq\ 1}$:

> 1. \begin{align}\boxed{\ds{\sum_{n\ =\ 1}^{2N}{\pars{-1}^{n - 1} \over n^{a}}}}
>    &=\sum_{n\ =\ 1}^{N}{1 \over \pars{2n - 1}^{a}}
>    -\sum_{n\ =\ 1}^{N}{1 \over \pars{2n}^{a}}
>    \\[5mm]&=\sum_{n\ =\ 1}^{N}{1 \over n^{a}}
>    -\sum_{n\ =\ 1}^{N}{1 \over \pars{2n}^{a}}
>    -\sum_{n\ =\ 1}^{N}{1 \over \pars{2n}^{a}}
>    =\boxed{\ds{\pars{1 - 2^{1 - a}}\sum_{n\ =\ 1}^{N}{1 \over n^{a}}}}
>    \end{align}
> 2. Similarly,
>      \begin{align}\boxed{\ds{\sum_{n\ =\ 1}^{2N - 1}{\pars{-1}^{n - 1} \over n^{a}}}}
>    &=\sum_{n\ =\ 1}^{N}{1 \over \pars{2n - 1}^{a}}
>    -\sum_{n\ =\ 1}^{N - 1}{1 \over \pars{2n}^{a}}
>    \\[5mm]&=\sum_{n\ =\ 1}^{N}{1 \over n^{a}}
>    -\sum_{n\ =\ 1}^{N}{1 \over \pars{2n}^{a}}
>    -\sum_{n\ =\ 1}^{N}{1 \over \pars{2n}^{a}} + {1 \over \pars{2N}^{a}}
>    \\[5mm]&=\boxed{\ds{\pars{1 - 2^{1 - a}}\sum_{n\ =\ 1}^{N}{1 \over n^{a}}
>    + {1 \over \pars{2N}^{a}}}}
>    \end{align}

Then,

1. When $\ds{a > 1}$ we get
   $$
   \sum_{n\ =\ 1}^{\infty}{\pars{-1}^{n - 1} \over n^{a}}
   =\pars{1 - 2^{1 - a}}\zeta\pars{a}
   $$
2. However, when $\ds{0\ <\ a\ \leq\ 1}$ 'we'll get a divergence' because
   $\ds{\sum_{n\ =\ 1}^{N}{1 \over n^{a}}}$ diverges. In any case, it's true that
   $\ds{\lim_{a\ \to\ 0^{+}}\pars{1 - 2^{1 - a}}\zeta\pars{a}=\half}$. In another words, it requires to interpret the sum as proportional to a Riemman Zeta function which involves an analytical continuation.